# Windows C++ wrong icon being displayed in explorer with multiple icons in resources file

Tags: c++, windows, wxwidgets

I have a wxWidgets program where the `resources.rc` file has two icons in it.

- Program icon
- Exit program icon

The contents of my `resources.rc` is:

```
#include "wx/msw/wx.rc"
#include "common/version.h"

// Icons
// Note the icon is an embedded icon
// i.e. Windows will be able to pick an appropriate icon size from:
// 256,128,96,64,48,32,24,16
MyProgram_ICO ICON "..\\res\\app.ico"
EXIT_ICO ICON "..\\res\\exit.ico"


// VS_VERSION_INFO etc
```

Explorer is showing my program with *EXIT_ICO*. Clearing the explorer cache, removing the *EXIT_ICO* entry, clean and build then shows the correct icon. But if I include it again, it picks the *EXIT_ICO* as the program icon.

My understanding of this is it would pick the first `ICON` entry in the resources file. I have also tried flipping the order to no avail. I don't understand why it's picking the *EXIT_ICO* one.

My program is still in development, so there will be more icons added to the resources file. The resources file is included in the `SRC` variable in CMake so it is being built with it

My program is being developed with wxWidgets, Visual Studio 2022 and CMake. I am developing the program in Windows 11.

Screenshots:

[image: with wrong icon] in explorer

[image: the correct icon] when running the program

Comment: You can find a better explanation in the file *samples/sample.rc* that comes with wxWidgets distribution.

Comment: @Ripi2 Thanks! The important bit was: _the icons are sorted both by their order and alphabetically (!)_ I prefixed my program's icon with an "a" and it is showing with the correct icon now
Would you like to convert your comment to an answer so I can mark as the correct answer?

Comment: I don't care. In fact, I didn't give an answer, just the path to it... :)
Any how, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Ripi2 in the comments, wxWidgets provides the crucial nugget of information as such:

```
// note that the icon used by the Explorer (i.e. the programs icon) is the
// first icon in the executable and the icons are sorted both by their order
// and alphabetically (!), so put this icon first and give it a name
// starting with "a"
```

[Source](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/samples/sample.rc#LL14C1-L17C21)

And the correct icon gets displayed in explorer now:

[image: correct icon]

My `resources.rc` file now looks like this:

```
#include "wx/msw/wx.rc"
#include "common/version.h"

// Icons
// Note the icon is an embedded icon
// i.e. Windows will be able to pick an appropriate icon size from:
// 256,128,96,64,48,32,24,16
aMyProgram_ICO ICON "..\\res\\taskies.ico"
EXIT_ICO ICON "..\\res\\exit.ico"
```

Comment: I use numerical constants for my icon IDs (as #defines).  Then you can just make it icon #1 (I think this is the 'official' way)

Comment: @PaulSanders I haven't actually done that in my wxWidgets + CMake programs... I just define my icons and it works. I don't have #defines as you've mentioned...

Comment: Well, whatever works.  wxWidgets might have wxWidgety ways of doing things.